# Getting total term frequency throughout entire index (Elasticsearch)

Tags: elasticsearch, information-retrieval

I am trying to calculate the total number of times a particular term occurs throughout an entire index (term collection frequency). I have attempted to do so through the use of term vectors, however this is restricted to a single document. Even in the case of terms that exist within a specified document, the response seems to max out at a certain doc_count (within field_statistics) which makes me doubtful of its accuracy.

Request:

```
http://myip:9200/clinicaltrials/trial/AVmk-ky6XMskTDwIwpih/_termvectors?term_statistics=true
```

The document id being used here is "AVmk-ky6XMskTDwIwpih", although the term statistics should not be specific to a document.

Response:

This is what I get for the term "cancer" for one of the fields:

```
 "cancer" : {
      "doc_freq" : 5297,
      "ttf" : 10587,
      "term_freq" : 1,
      "tokens" : [
        {
          "position" : 15,
          "start_offset" : 115,
          "end_offset" : 121
        }
      ]
    },
```

If I total the ttf for all fields, I get 18915. However, the actual total term frequency for "cancer" is in fact 542829. This leads me to believe that it is limiting the term_vector stats to a subset of documents within the index.

Any advice here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what elasticsearch version are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for the difference in the count is because term vectors are not accurate unless the index in question has a single shard. For indexes with multiple shards, the documents are distributed all over the shards, hence the frequency returned isn't the total but from a randomly selected shard.

Thus, the returned frequency is just a relative measure and not the absolute value you expect. [see the Behaviour section](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html).
To test this, you can create a single shard index and request the frequency (it should give you the actual total).

Answer (score 6):

I believe you need to turn term_statistics to true as per [elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html):

> Term statistics
>   Setting term_statistics to true (default is false) will return
>
> total term frequency (how often a term occurs in all documents)
>
> document frequency (the number of documents containing the current term)
>
> By default these values are not returned since term statistics can have a serious performance impact.

Comment: This may not have answered the question explicitly, but it does bring the docs up which I have missed, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried simply using COUNT API? 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/search-count.html

It can return the number of matches for a query. So something like this may work.

```
GET /my_index/_count
{
    "query" : {"match": {"my_field": "my_keyword"}
}
```